# UI5 Property Binding breaks when second binding expression is added

Tags: sapui5

I am having trouble getting a binding to work.

This is working fine: `<Title text="{= ${parts: ['user>/currentTenant', 'user>/tenants'], formatter: '.formatter.getTenant'}.name }"/>`

This doesn't render the control completely, nothing is logged:
`<Title text="{i18>currentTenant} {= ${parts: ['user>/currentTenant', 'user>/tenants'], formatter: '.formatter.getTenant'}.name }"/>`

When the first part is text instead of a binding to `i18n`, the result is the same.

When the `i18n` binding is *inside* the expression binding(`{= ${i18n>...} + ...}`), it is working as expected.

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

UI5 version: 1.96, Browser version: Chrome latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has ever worked. According to https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.CompositeBinding#overview:

> A nesting of composite bindings is currently not supported.

The 2nd binding (expression binding) is yet another instance of `CompositeBinding`.

Comment: PS: see also my additional comment at https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3565#issuecomment-1206774715 and further discussion as this limitation might change in the future.